# Python Regex masking key-value pairs in strings

Tags: python, regex, key-value, masking

I have a String like the following:-

```
"assdd ffdsfad 'result_secret_key': 'dfkfaj&^%2', 'auth_matrix': '213fsdf#', 'password': 'adsfa&&*!@#4' and 'app_auth': 'eff#@DS'  dafsdsaf adfs adlsfjasdkjf "
```

I need to mask all the keys containing words like secret, auth, key and password.

I mean to say like 'result_secret_key': '*****'

Can someone suggest me a regex pattern for doing this in Python.

The ultimate string should look like:-

```
"assdd ffdsfad 'result_secret_key': '******', 'auth_matrix': '******','password': '******' and 'app_auth': '******'  dafsdsaf adfs adlsfjasdkjf "
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = "assdd ffdsfad 'result_secret_key': 'dfkfaj&^%2', 'auth_matrix': '213fsdf#', 'password': 'adsfa&&*!@#4' and 'app_auth': 'eff#@DS'  dafsdsaf adfs adlsfjasdkjf "
>>> re.sub(r"('\S*?(?:secret|auth|key|password)\S*?'\s*:\s*')[^']*(?=')", r'\1******', s)
"assdd ffdsfad 'result_secret_key': '******', 'auth_matrix': '******', 'password': '******' and 'app_auth': '******'  dafsdsaf adfs adlsfjasdkjf "
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters and  `(?:secret|auth|key|password)` matches a single word from the given list.

Answer (score 1):

Avinash Raj's answer might be better...
but here is another:

```
re.sub(": '.*?'",r": '***'",s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
('[^']*?(?=secret|auth|key|password)[^']*':\s*')[^']*'
```

Try this.Replace by `\1****'`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/12

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\'[^\']*?(?=secret|auth|key|password)[^\']*\':\s*\')[^\']*\'')
test_str = u"assdd ffdsfad 'result_secret_key': 'dfkfaj&^%2', 'auth_matrix': '213fsdf#', 'password': 'adsfa&&*!@#4' and 'app_auth': 'eff#@DS' dafsdsaf adfs adlsfjasdkjf "
subst = u"\1****'"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```